# Infinite continued fractions

Tags: continued-fractions

I am fascinated by the fact that "important" irrational numbers like the golden ratio, base of the natural exponent, pi, square roots have a "regular" representation as an infinite continued fraction.

Is there some correspondence between "having a regular ICF representation" and the "importance" of a number, whatever the meaning of "importance" might be? Is this a thing, or is such connection spurious and you could find a "regular" representation for any irrational number if you wanted to?

The opposite question also interests me: if I choose some "regular" representation like `[1;1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,6,...]` what are the chances for it's not going to be a square root of some number, for example?

Comment: It won't be a quadratic irrational, since those are the numbers with eventually periodic continued fractions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is no known pattern in the continued fraction for $\pi$. Lagrange proved that the continued fraction representation of a positive  real number $x$ is eventually periodic iff $x$ is the root of a quadratic with integer coefficients. There is a big subject called [diophantine approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation) that grapples with questions like these.